# How to simplify the initialization of List<List<Int32>> as IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Int32>>?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable, new-operator, nested-lists

I am doing the following collection initialisation:

```
Int32[,] v1 = new Int32[2, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };

IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Int32>> v2 = new List<List<Int32>> { { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

On the second line I get the error:

```
No overload for method 'Add' takes 2 arguments
```

Is there a way, using the latest C# version, to create an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Int32>>` without adding `new List<Int32>` for each item inside the main collection?

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Int32>> v2 = new List<List<Int32>> { 
  new List<Int32> { 2, 3 }, 
  new List<Int32> { 3, 4 } 
};
```

Comment: [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to write a wrapper around `List<List<T>>`!

Collection initializers are just syntactic sugar to call a method called `Add` declared by the object, and `List<T>` doesn't declare an `Add` method which takes 2 parameters (or any number of parameters above 1).

*However*, a collection initializer will also call an extension method called `Add`. This means we can write this:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
     public static void Add<T>(this List<List<T>> list, params T[] items)
     {
         list.Add(new List<T>(items));
     }
}
```

Which lets us then write:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> collection = new List<List<int>>()
{
    { 1, 2 },
    { 3, 4 },
};
```

[See it working here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pdCq4L).

---

It's worth noting that this sort of `Add` method can only be added as an extension method -- it would be impossible for `List<T>` to declare it itself. The reason for this is that it only makes sense when the list contains other lists, and there's no way to define an instance method which only applies for some types of list. However, you can add all sorts of restrictions like this on extension methods. You can write an extension method on `List<T>` which only applies when `T` is a class, or indeed only when `T` is another list!

Comment: Just for curiosity, you wrote `Add()` method as an `extension` method for `List<List<T>>`. How compiler will differentiate between extension method and predefined `Add` function of `List<T>`. I am asking this because of *An extension method will never be called if it has the same signature as a method defined in the type.* [from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#general-guidelines)

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar The extension method doesn't have the same signature as the instance method - it's clearly different. If you took away the extension method and wrote `var list = new List<List<int>>(); list.Add(1, 2)`, that's obviously a compiler error: there's no method on `List<T>` which takes 2 parameters. Therefore there's no conflict between an extension method and the instance method. Even if you wrote `list.Add(1)`, that's still a compiler error, as the `Add` method on `List<List<int>>` only acceps a `List<int>`, not an `int`.

Comment: yeah you are correct. `Add()` method takes a single parameter to store into the list, but in your case you are storing `T[]` which makes this two `Add()` methods different from each other. Am I correct or still missing something?

Comment: It's even simpler than that: `List<List<int>>.Add` takes a `List<int>`, so the only way to call it is with `list.Add(new List<int>() { .. })`. My extension method takes individual `ints`, so you can call it as `list.Add(1, 2, 3, ...)`. They've got different parameter types.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/onVyT4 . When you pass individual ints, or an array of ints, it chooses the `Add(params int[] values)` extension method. When you pass a `List<int>`, it chooses the instance `Add(List<T> item)` overload.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Object and Collection Initializers article in the C# Programming Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

> Collection initializers let you specify one or more element initializers when you initialize a collection type that implements `IEnumerable` and has `Add` **with the appropriate signature** as an instance method or an extension method.

So, the problem here is that no appropriate overload for `List<T>.Add()` takes a variable number of arguments.

If you define a custom collection type you can add an `Add()` method that takes a `params` argument:

```cs
class NestedList<T> : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    List<List<T>> _list;

    public NestedList()
    {
        _list = new List<List<T>>();
    }

    public void Add(params T[] innerItems)
    {
        _list.Add(new List<T>(innerItems));
    }

    public IEnumerator<IEnumerable<TI>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now that we have an `Add()` method that takes a variable amount of arguments, you can use nested initializers:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> v2 = new NestedList<int> { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```